# How to change the default browsing language on browsers?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, browser, language

I am living in Switzerland near the french part, so I speak french. Unfortunately, when I install a new PC and open a browser (any kind of browser), most pages are displayed in german because somehow it think that in Switzerland everybody speaks german...

I don't really understand how the browser understands what language it should use to display pages. There a no locale settings on most browsers (Firefox, Chrome, Edge...) and the language option is the browser display language, not what language is used to display pages.

How can I change this?

If I lookup from my IP, I get these locales: `de-CH, fr-CH, it-CH, rm`, so of course websites that use the IP to get the language will guess wrong.

I have Windows 11, operating system language in English, locale set to `en_CH`

Here some examples:

[image]
[image]

So the question is: how to get Digi-Key in English or in French by default?

Comment: How you change it depends on the website.  Most websites like Google use Geo location to determine which language should be displayed.  This behavior isn't handled by the browser.

Comment: *"How can I change this?"* - Use a proxy in a French-speaking country to browse the web?

Comment: A screenshot with example website would be helpful. Also, what is your OS/install language and browser/install language? Different language versions of Firefox are at: [Choose which Firefox Browser to download in your language](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/all/#product-desktop-release). This may be different than just specifying menus language in Settings.

Comment: Often page content display language is controlled by the page itself. In Firefox, go to View Page Source and check the headers for something like lang="en" or lang="ja".